# how to calculate line height for text truncate?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using text truncate by height currently like this

```
const lineHeight = 90
```

that's the initial height for calculation with scroll height.

```
const calculateHeight = () => {
    const scrollHeight = para?.current.scrollHeight
    const isGreater = (lineHeight >= scrollHeight)
    setIsGreaterParaHeight(isGreater)
  }
```

and that's the calculation function

the issue is I want to do the calculation by props when someone passes line=1 so it will do the calculation for line 1 height how can I achieve that currently it's working for 3 lines by hardcoded 90 height

Comment: Can you simulate your code in a **codesandbox** environment ?

Comment: Sure

https://codesandbox.io/s/aged-breeze-bbqel